# PHP WebSocket Server using SSL

Tags: php, ssl, websocket

I am trying to use websockets in my application which running in this environment :
- Debian 8
- Apache 2.4.10
- PHP 5.6.30
I use devristo/phpws package, and just trying to make their example works (time).
Everything is ok on a HTTP context website and ws:// protocol connection, but when i try to put it on an HTTPS website and using wss:// protocol, it fail.

I start the server via "php -q server.php", file content :

```
<?php
require_once("vendor/autoload.php");
use Devristo\Phpws\Server\WebSocketServer;

$loop = \React\EventLoop\Factory::create();

// Create a logger which writes everything to the STDOUT
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$writer = new Zend\Log\Writer\Stream("php://output");
$logger->addWriter($writer);

// Create a WebSocket server using SSL
$server = new WebSocketServer("wss://X.X.X.X:9300", $loop, $logger);

$loop->addPeriodicTimer(0.5, function() use($server, $logger){
    $time = new DateTime();
    $string = $time->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $logger->notice("Broadcasting time to all clients: $string");
    foreach($server->getConnections() as $client)
        $client->sendString($string);
});

// Bind the server
$server->bind();

// Start the event loop
$loop->run();
```

In other hand, i have a time.html, which contain :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>WebSocket TEST</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Server Time</h1>
<strong id="time"></strong>

<script>
    var socket = new WebSocket("wss://X.X.X.X:9300/");
    socket.onmessage = function(msg) {
        document.getElementById("time").innerText = msg.data;
    };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The server start running without problems :

```
2017-11-24T11:47:57+01:00 NOTICE (5): phpws listening on ssl://X.X.X.X:9300
2017-11-24T11:47:57+01:00 NOTICE (5): Broadcasting time to all clients: 2017-11-24 11:47:57
2017-11-24T11:47:58+01:00 NOTICE (5): Broadcasting time to all clients: 2017-11-24 11:47:58
....
```

When i go on my page time.html in browser, the following JavaScript error comes in chrome :

```
VM725:164 WebSocket connection to 'wss://X.X.X.X:9300/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH
```

At the same time, server produces this error output :

```
PHP Warning:  stream_socket_accept(): SSL_R_NO_SHARED_CIPHER: no suitable shared cipher could be used.  This could be because the server is missing an SSL certificate (local_cert context option) in /var/www/web/sofive/k-zam/web/vendor/devristo/phpws/src/Devristo/Phpws/Server/WebSocketServer.php on line 141

Warning: stream_socket_accept(): SSL_R_NO_SHARED_CIPHER: no suitable shared cipher could be used.  This could be because the server is missing an SSL certificate (local_cert context option) in /var/www/web/sofive/k-zam/web/vendor/devristo/phpws/src/Devristo/Phpws/Server/WebSocketServer.php on line 141
PHP Warning:  stream_socket_accept(): Failed to enable crypto in /var/www/web/wstest/vendor/devristo/phpws/src/Devristo/Phpws/Server/WebSocketServer.php on line 141

Warning: stream_socket_accept(): Failed to enable crypto in /var/www/web/wstest/vendor/devristo/phpws/src/Devristo/Phpws/Server/WebSocketServer.php on line 141
PHP Warning:  stream_socket_accept(): accept failed: Success in /var/www/web/wstest/vendor/devristo/phpws/src/Devristo/Phpws/Server/WebSocketServer.php on line 141

Warning: stream_socket_accept(): accept failed: Success in /var/www/web/wstest/vendor/devristo/phpws/src/Devristo/Phpws/Server/WebSocketServer.php on line 141
```

So i think i miss a certificate to pass to socket_context_create ? If yes, how to create this certificate, are there specs (ssl version ? etc), or do i need to pass the same as the one used for https website (generated with let's encrypt certbot) ?